# Function not running in code but works in Chrome Console (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, tinymce, web-inspector

I have a TinyMCE iframe running on one of my textareas with the prism.js script loaded (in the iframe). Prism has a function, highlightAll(), which should be possible to run by calling Prism.highlightAll(). It should then run through the page and syntax highlight all code.

If I have a freshly reloaded page and add a code block (which will generate a  block) and run Prism.highlightAll() from TinyMCE, nothing happens. If I run the function from the console nothing happens. However, if I "Inspect" the code block and then run the function from the inspector it works as it should, the code gets syntax highlighted. However, running the function from TinyMCE still doesn't work.

I find this very strange. Why is it that it works from the console after I've inspected the iframe, but I can't get the function to run from code within the iframe?

Thank you!

Comment: it seems that your code has timing issue. when you run from console at that time your other codes are executed so probably the code has all its dependencies ready

Comment: Ok, can I test that in some way? If I can run the function from the console should it work in the code then as well, or does the console do some magic that the code does not do?

Comment: are you using jquery? if yes, you can place your code in $(document){} and place your code after you initialize tinymce